# Is it safe to use document.write inside a IIFE function

Tags: javascript

I've read that it is not safe to use document.write inside an async function since it can delete all you have. But, is it safe to have:

```
(function() {
  function one() {
      document.write('whatever here');
  }
  one();
})();
```

I'm not a fan of document.write, but I'm looking into an external JS having this.

Comment: It has the same effect as simply writing `document.write('whatever');`  on its own ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's perfectly fine, assuming that the code is being run during the page load.

There's nothing about the IIFE that would make this asynchronous.

Your code could be rewritten as:

```
function one() {
    document.write('whatever here');
}

function main() {
  one();
}

main();
```

Other than introducing more function names, this is exactly the same thing. It may be more apparent this way that there's no asynchronous code here.